# JSFML depth buffer not working

Tags: java, opengl, sfml

So, I'm working on a game with OpenGL and Java, and I've decided to use JSFML for my windowing, text, image loading, etc... And, i'm having some small issues.

The OpenGL drawing works fine until I try to play with depth then it just doesn't work!

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.jsfml.graphics.*;
import org.jsfml.window.*;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
//import static org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU.*;

public class Main
{
    static Image icon;
    static Texture playert;
    static long a, b, c, d;
    static float e;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        c = 0l;
        icon = new Image();
        icon.loadFromStream(new FileInputStream("Icon.png"));
        ContextSettings contextSettings;

        contextSettings = new ContextSettings (24, 8, 0, 2, 1);

        VideoMode v = new VideoMode(800, 600);

        RenderWindow window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Game", org.jsfml.window.WindowStyle.DEFAULT, contextSettings);
        window.setIcon(icon);
        window.setFramerateLimit(120);
        Context.getContext().setActive(true);
        Text pauseMessage = new Text();
        Font font = new Font();
        font.loadFromStream(new FileInputStream("Minecraftia.ttf"));
        pauseMessage.setFont(font);
        pauseMessage.setCharacterSize(20);
        pauseMessage.setPosition(0.f, 0.f);
        pauseMessage.setColor(new Color(250, 250, 250));
        pauseMessage.setString("This is Mission:Iinfinity, prototyped in JSFML");
        Text fps = new Text();
        fps.setFont(font);
        fps.setCharacterSize(20);
        fps.setPosition(0.f, 20.f);
        fps.setColor(new Color(250, 250, 250));
        fps.setString("FPS: " + c);

        org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.useContext(Context.getContext());
        glDepthMask(true);
        glClearDepth(1.f);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        float ratio = window.getSize().x / window.getSize().y;
        glFrustum(-ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 500.f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        a = System.currentTimeMillis();
        d = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true)
        {
            window.clear();
            if(b - a >= 1000)
            {
                a = b;
                fps.setString("FPS: " + c);
                c = 0;
            }
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            window.pushGLStates();
            window.draw(pauseMessage);
            window.draw(fps);
            window.popGLStates();
            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -10f);
            //glRotatef(10f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glVertex3f(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
            glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
            glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0);
            glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
            glEnd();
            glPopMatrix();
            window.display();
            if(Keyboard.isKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.ESCAPE))
            {
                window.close();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            b = System.currentTimeMillis();
            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ok, fixed the ContextSettings but that cube still stubbornly refuses to draw further than 1 coord deep or 1 coord back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is not working, you are constructing the `ContextSettings` class object this way:

```
contextSettings = new ContextSettings(0, 4, 2, 32, 32);
```

The meaning of each parameter in the constructor is, in order:

1. int depthBits
2. int stencilBits
3. int antialiasingLevel
4. int majorVersion
5. int minorVersion

You are requesting a render-context that has a 0-bit depth buffer, 4-bit stencil buffer, 2x MSAA, and OpenGL 32.32!

Consider something a little bit more sane like this:

```
contextSettings = new ContextSettings (24, 8, 0, 2, 1);
```

24-bit Depth, 8-Bit Stencil, 0x MSAA, OpenGL 2.1.